# How can I change two lines of text into one via CSS please?

Tags: html, css

I'd like to ask you  experts a CSS-based question, which I think will probably be too easy for you to answer. I've tried - but failed.

http://codepen.io/fatihturan/pen/iLgub

I've seen this pen and really appreciate the effect - though it would be perfect if the text could be on one line, such as this:

Title: Foo

- and keeping the hidden scrolling intact.

Thanks!
Rob

```
  <div class="badge">
    <span class="title">Title:</span>
    <div>
      <span class="first">Foo</span>
      <span class="second">Bar</span>
    </div>
  </div>


body {
  background:#fff;
  font:14px "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.badge {
  margin:100px auto;
  width:80px;
  height:40px;
  padding:10px 0px;
  border-radius:4px;
  background-color:#e3e3e3;
  box-shadow:0 1px rgba(255,255,255,.75), inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
  text-align:center;
  color:#949494;
  line-height:14px;
  text-shadow:0 1px 0 #fff;
  div {
    overflow:hidden;
    padding:2px 0;
    height:16px;
  }
  span {
    display:block;
    font-size:18px;
    color:#8b8b8b;
    cursor:default;
  }
  &:hover {
      .first {
        top:-20px;
      }
      .second {
        top:-19px;
      }
  }
}

.title {
  margin-bottom:5px;
  font-size:12px;
  font-weight:100;
}

.first, .second {
  position:relative;
  top:0;
  transition:top .1s ease-in;
  -webkit-transition:top .1s ease-in;
  -moz-transition:top .1s ease-in;
}

.first {
  margin-bottom:5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see my update in link

[codeopen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EjXPKE)

```
    body {
  background:#fff;
  font:14px "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.badge {
  margin:100px auto;
  width:150px;
  height:20px;
  padding:10px 0px;
  border-radius:4px;
  background-color:#e3e3e3;
  box-shadow:0 1px rgba(255,255,255,.75), inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
  text-align:center;
  color:#949494;
  line-height:14px;
  text-shadow:0 1px 0 #fff;
  div {
    overflow:hidden;
    padding:2px 0;
    height:16px;
  }
  span {
    display:block;
    font-size:18px;
    color:#8b8b8b;
    cursor:default;
  }
  &:hover {
      .first {
        top:-20px;
      }
      .second {
        top:-19px;
      }
  }
}

.title {
  margin-bottom:5px;
  font-size:12px;
  font-weight:100;
  width:50%;
  float:left;
}

.first, .second {
  position:relative;
  top:0;
  transition:top .1s ease-in;
  -webkit-transition:top .1s ease-in;
  -moz-transition:top .1s ease-in;
}

.first {
  margin-bottom:5px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks also for this! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Just use:

```
display: inline;
```

instead of

```
display: block;
```

on the spans.

*P.S. Your code isn't a valid CSS. That is SCSS which has to be compiled into CSS!*

Comment: Display inline breaks the scrolling text animation.

Comment: He wants them on one line. I can't imagine what the scroll animation would be for in this case. :D

Comment: This is not a valid answer. He wants to combine lines into one without breaking the scrolling text animation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement `-webkit-box` to badge class.

[Working demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bdREpV)

`-webkit-box` has been supported by IE9+ , Firefox, Chrome, Safari and Opera.